# How to transfer GPS data to another shield while making data readable

Tags: arduino, i2c

I am using two Arduino UNOs connected in I2C.
I am working on a project to log GPS data on a SD card then when one of my boards connects to my network it prints the data collected over a server. At the moment i have the GPS data being  written to the SD card on the GPS board. The problem i was having with that was when sending that data to the wifi shield on the other board to write it to the server. Now i want to bypass the SD card on the GPS shield and write the data straight to the SD card on the wifi shield. The code that i have is an example code from Ada-fruit and not being the a good programmer i'm not sure how to take the code i have and do that.

This is the code on the GPS shield

```
#include <Adafruit_GPS.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <GPSconfig.h>
#include <Wire.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(8, 6);
Adafruit_GPS GPS(&mySerial);

// Set GPSECHO to 'false' to turn off echoing the GPS data to the Serial console
// Set to 'true' if you want to debug and listen to the raw GPS sentences
#define GPSECHO  true
/* set to true to only log to SD when GPS has a fix, for debugging, keep it false */
#define LOG_FIXONLY false  

// Set the pins used
#define ledPin 13

// read a Hex value and return the decimal equivalent
uint8_t parseHex(char c) {
  if (c < '0')
    return 0;
  if (c <= '9')
    return c - '0';
  if (c < 'A')
    return 0;
  if (c <= 'F')
    return (c - 'A')+10;
  }


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("\r\nUltimate GPSlogger Shield");
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);


  // make sure that the default chip select pin is set to
  // output, even if you don't use it

  // connect to the GPS at the desired rate
  GPS.begin(9600);

  // uncomment this line to turn on RMC (recommended minimum) and GGA (fix data)           including altitude
  GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_OUTPUT_RMCGGA);
  // uncomment this line to turn on only the "minimum recommended" data
  //GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_OUTPUT_RMCONLY);
  // For logging data, we don't suggest using anything but either RMC only or RMC+GGA
  // to keep the log files at a reasonable size
  // Set the update rate
  GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_UPDATE_1HZ);   // 1 or 5 Hz update rate

  // Turn off updates on antenna status, if the firmware permits it
  GPS.sendCommand(PGCMD_NOANTENNA);

  Serial.println("Ready!");
}

void loop() {
  char c = GPS.read();
  if (GPSECHO)
     if (c)   Serial.print(c);

  // if a sentence is received, we can check the checksum, parse it...
  if (GPS.newNMEAreceived()) {
    // a tricky thing here is if we print the NMEA sentence, or data
    // we end up not listening and catching other sentences! 
    // so be very wary if using OUTPUT_ALLDATA and trying to print out data
    //Serial.println(GPS.lastNMEA());   // this also sets the newNMEAreceived() flag to   false

    if (!GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA()))   // this also sets the newNMEAreceived() flag to false
      return;  // we can fail to parse a sentence in which case we should just wait for another

    // Sentence parsed! 
    Serial.println("OK");
    if (LOG_FIXONLY && !GPS.fix) {
        Serial.print("No Fix");
        return;
    }

    // Rad. lets log it!
    Serial.println("Log");

    char *stringptr = GPS.lastNMEA();
    uint8_t stringsize = strlen(stringptr);
    if (stringsize != Wire.write((uint8_t *)stringptr, stringsize))    //write the     string     to the SD file
    if (strstr(stringptr, "RMC"))  
     Serial.println();
   }
 }
```

The last 5 lines is where the data is written to the card. At the top of the code above setup is the code used to make the GPS data readable. The last 5 lines is what I need to change and i'm not sure what i need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have both SD cards in parallel? I mean, two shields (GPS and WiFi) stacked?

On your case, the string is being sent via I2C to the GPS Shield... How is the wiring between the WiFi shield and the Arduino? Can you show us the schematics?